# How to get ajax responses from php?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I run the ajax via this php with js:

```
 function ajax_Person() { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery("#createCat").on("click", function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      person();
    });
    function person(){
      jQuery.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        type: 'post',
        data: { action: 'data_person', catName: jQuery('#newCat').val(), catDesc: jQuery('#descRiption').val() },
        success: function(data) {
          jQuery(".modal-body").html("Done!");
        }
      });
    }
    </script>
  <?php }
```

Then I run

```
  function data_person(){
    $catname = $_POST['catName'];
    $catdesc = $_POST["catDesc"];
    $cat_ID = get_cat_ID( sanitize_title_for_query($catname) );  
    // Check if category exists
    if($cat_ID == 0) {
        $cat_name = $catname;  
        $cat_desc = $catdesc;
        $cat_slug = sanitize_title_with_dashes($cat_name);
        $my_cat = array(
          'cat_name' => $cat_name, 
          'category_description' => $cat_desc, 
          'category_nicename' => $cat_slug, 
          'category_parent' => 0
        );
        if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {
          echo 'Category added successfully';
        } else {
          echo 'Error while creating new category';
        }
    } else {
      echo 'That category already exists';
    }
  }
```

In both cases I get "Done!" as a response. I need to set up responses based on:

```
   if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {
          echo 'Category added successfully';
        } else {
          echo 'Error while creating new category';
        }
    } else {
      echo 'That category already exists';
    }
```

The above php bits work if I run them as a standard php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

on your php

```
 if( wp_insert_category( $my_cat ) ) {
      echo json_encode( 'Category added successfully');
    } else {
      echo json_encode( 'Error while creating new category');
    }
} else {
  echo json_encode( 'That category already exists');
}
```

on js instead

```
 $(".modal-body").html("Done!");
```

use

```
  $(".modal-body").html(data);
```

Comment: Excellent thanks. One thing, Any idea why is giving 0 at the end too? "That category already exists"0

Comment: I had to add `exit;` at the end of the php